# How to create a two dimensional array in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures

How to create a two dimensional array in python. Specifically by initiating it with an existing array for the first index.

I have an array:

```
x = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
```

and I want to create a new one from it:

```
y = [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]]
```

How can I convert x to y

I am using Python 3.

Comment: You mean `y = [x]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> x = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
```

You want to put `x` in a list, to get `[x]`. Hmm...

```
>>> y = [x]
>>> y
[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]]
```

Yay!

---

In Python, it's best to try the obvious approach first. To quote the Zen of Python:

> There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
>   Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.

Answer (score 2):

`y = [x]` should do the trick. You're wrapping the list `x` in a new list.